# publish changes to notification progress bar

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification containing a progressbar. The progressBar update code runs in a service.Code is below

```
notificationManager.notify(42, notification);

while((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1)
{
    //new 
    downloadProgress += count;
    outputStream.write(data,0,count);
    //new
    notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, contentLength, downloadProgress, false);
    notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
}
```

The problem I m facing is since the `notificatoinManager.notify()` method is called in between the data read from the stream , It slows the copy process.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I didn't think something like that would slow down the download process significantly :P
Maybe you could update the bar (call the notification methods) in a new thread...

Comment: yeah neither did I until I executed the code.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably use an AsyncTask to seperate out UI updating from actual reading

```
public class ReadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
@Override 
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {    
//Do the reading here
downloadProgress += count;    
outputStream.write(data,0,count);
publishProgress(downloadProgress);
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, contentLength, downloadProgress, false);       
notificationManager.notify(42, notification);               
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree with Royston...you can use an AsyncTask, even if it is running in a service!

Comment: AsyncTask can also be used with a Service.

Comment: Hmm Okay so I read the AsyncTask documentation. It says it should only be used for operation which lasts for few seconds ! . The download operation can take minutes. Would its be fine to use it in such case ?

Comment: I use AsyncTask for my downloads and i have found it very good! You can use it without any worry, it will work fine.